# A Tag Rendering

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink

I wish for every external 'A' link to have the attibute set for Target but all internal links to be ignored

Example:

```html
<a href="http://www.somelink here" title="Some Title">Some Text</a>
```

to become:

```html
<a href="http://www.somelink here" title="Some Title" target="_blank">Some Text</a>
```

but leave alone any non http links (mailto, ~/, /../PageName.aspx etc.

I wrote a VB.NET (not c#) Class which I added to my APP_CODE folder of my web project but the code is completely ignored


`Public Class MyLinks
    Inherits HyperLink
    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        Dim alink As HyperLink = Me
        If alink.NavigateUrl.StartsWith("http") Then
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, alink.NavigateUrl)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Title, alink.Text)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, alink.Text)
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Target, "_blank")
            writer.RenderEndTag()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class`


Obviously, I do not wish for my website to contain thousands of hyperlink controls but I inherited from it as I didn't know another way to access the href and tex attributes.

What am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to do with jQuery, just add this:

```
$(document).on('click', "a[href^='http']:not([href*='" + window.location.host + "'][target='_blank']),a[href^='//']:not([href*='" + window.location.host + "'][target='_blank']),a[href$='.pdf'],a[href$='.xls'],a[href$='.xlsx'],a[href$='.doc'],a[href$='.docx'],a[href$='.ppt'],a[href$='.pptx']", null, function () {
$(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Not interested in that approach as I am talking about 5000 + links so I want it done by code behind because it's going into a DLL

Comment: If you insist on doing it in code behind (which I think is a bad idea), then you would need to change all your links to use your new control (MyLinks).  Additionally, instead of throwing out the entire render of hyperlink, why not just change the target attribute and let the base class render it like normal?

Comment: There is a way to force all hyperlink controls to instead use your control, but I don't remember exactly how to do it other than it's a change in web.config.  And the code I gave you above works great.  Just place it in whatever your site wide javascript file is (our is site.js), and it's working on a site with well over a million links.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Microsoft do an article about rendering the Hyperlink control but I am using html a links instead. I see that someone else on the Internet did in fact ask a similar question. I think Yet Another Forum (YAF) do the same and have downloaded the Github source code (in C#) and will see how they do it. I know they use a ViewState element to hold the Boolean value (Open all links in a new window = True|False) but I would just have it set to true and check the StartsWith("http") then perform it. Again, YAF do this in a DLL too which you think is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I overrode the Render method in the code behind. http://forums.asp.net/t/509737.aspx?override+the+href+tag+of+a+LinkButton. The code on this page for NewWindow gave me the idea.